# Is there anything like RhinoMocks in Java?

Tags: java, mocking, rhino-mocks

What would be the closest resemblance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/).  RhinoMocks was built off the EasyMock.NET engine, so there are a lot of similarities.

Comment: From RhinoMock site:
It's a hybrid approach between the pure Record/Replay of EasyMock.Net's model and NMock's expectation based model. Rhino.Mocks originated from EasyMock.Net...

Answer (score 1):

I know [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) is very similar to RhinoMocks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Mockito (.net and java mocking)

http://code.google.com/p/mockito/